# Azure SQL Server ARM template deployment error messages

Tags: sql-server, azure, templates, azure-resource-manager

When deploying an ARM template for a single Azure SQL Server using the portal's exported template I get these errors that I cannot understand/classify/resolve. What does it want from me???

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : ... Resource Microsoft.Sql/servers...
- ./advisors 'sqls01/DbParameterization' failed
- ./advisors 'sqls01/DefragmentIndex' failed
- ./vulnerabilityAssessments 'sqls01/Default' failed
- ./databases/auditingPolicies 'sqls01/master/Default' failed
- ./databases/auditingSettings 'sqls01/master/Default' failed
- ./databases/vulnerabilityAssessments 'sqls01/master/Default' failed

The server deploys correctly, though; the template is working fine otherwise. Are these errors only 'warnings'; can they be ignored? How to supress them if so?

This is just to automate a standard Azure SQL Server deployment; automatic tuning, auditing etc are not configured (only transparent data encryption is). I googled the error messages, and also searched here but to no avail.

Does anyone see the same issue - surely I cannot release a deployment set that throws such four pages of red error lines even as the deployment succeeds what I can see in the resource group.

Here the ARM template's SQL Server parts for it:

`,
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
            "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
            "name": "[parameters('servers_initialsql01_name')]",
            "location": "[variables('rgLocation')]",
            "kind": "v12.0",
            "properties": {
                "administratorLogin": "[parameters('sqls01LI')]",
                "administratorLoginPassword": "[parameters('sqls01PW')]",
                "version": "12.0"
            }
        },`
...

`,
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/advisors",
            "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('servers_initialsql01_name'), '/CreateIndex')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('servers_initialsql01_name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "autoExecuteValue": "Disabled"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/advisors",
            "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('servers_initialsql01_name'), '/DbParameterization')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('servers_initialsql01_name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "autoExecuteValue": "Disabled"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/advisors",
            "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('servers_initialsql01_name'), '/DefragmentIndex')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('servers_initialsql01_name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "autoExecuteValue": "Disabled"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/advisors",
            "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('servers_initialsql01_name'), '/DropIndex')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('servers_initialsql01_name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "autoExecuteValue": "Disabled"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/advisors",
            "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('servers_initialsql01_name'), '/ForceLastGoodPlan')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('servers_initialsql01_name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "autoExecuteValue": "Disabled"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/auditingPolicies",
            "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('servers_initialsql01_name'), '/Default')]",
            "location": "[variables('rgLocation')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('servers_initialsql01_name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "auditingState": "Disabled"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/auditingSettings",
            "apiVersion": "2017-03-01-preview",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('servers_initialsql01_name'), '/Default')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('servers_initialsql01_name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "state": "Disabled",
                "retentionDays": 0,
                "auditActionsAndGroups": [],
                "storageAccountSubscriptionId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "isStorageSecondaryKeyInUse": false
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/auditingPolicies",
            "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('servers_initialsql01_name'), '/master/Default')]",
            "location": "[variables('rgLocation')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('servers_initialsql01_name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "auditingState": "Disabled"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/auditingSettings",
            "apiVersion": "2017-03-01-preview",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('servers_initialsql01_name'), '/master/Default')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('servers_initialsql01_name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "state": "Disabled",
                "retentionDays": 0,
                "storageAccountSubscriptionId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "isStorageSecondaryKeyInUse": false
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/geoBackupPolicies",
            "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('servers_initialsql01_name'), '/master/Default')]",
            "location": "[variables('rgLocation')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('servers_initialsql01_name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "state": "Enabled"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/securityAlertPolicies",
            "apiVersion": "2018-06-01-preview",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('servers_initialsql01_name'), '/master/Default')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('servers_initialsql01_name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "state": "Disabled",
                "disabledAlerts": [
                    ""
                ],
                "emailAddresses": [
                    ""
                ],
                "emailAccountAdmins": false,
                "retentionDays": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/transparentDataEncryption",
            "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('servers_initialsql01_name'), '/master/current')]",
            "location": "[variables('rgLocation')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('servers_initialsql01_name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "status": "Disabled"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/vulnerabilityAssessments",
            "apiVersion": "2017-03-01-preview",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('servers_initialsql01_name'), '/master/Default')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('servers_initialsql01_name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "recurringScans": {
                    "isEnabled": false,
                    "emailSubscriptionAdmins": true
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/encryptionProtector",
            "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('servers_initialsql01_name'), '/current')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('servers_initialsql01_name'))]"
            ],
            "kind": "servicemanaged",
            "properties": {
                "serverKeyName": "ServiceManaged",
                "serverKeyType": "ServiceManaged"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/firewallRules",
            "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('servers_initialsql01_name'), '/AllowAllWindowsAzureIps')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('servers_initialsql01_name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "startIpAddress": "0.0.0.0",
                "endIpAddress": "0.0.0.0"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/keys",
            "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('servers_initialsql01_name'), '/ServiceManaged')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('servers_initialsql01_name'))]"
            ],
            "kind": "servicemanaged",
            "properties": {
                "serverKeyType": "ServiceManaged"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/securityAlertPolicies",
            "apiVersion": "2017-03-01-preview",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('servers_initialsql01_name'), '/Default')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('servers_initialsql01_name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "state": "Disabled",
                "disabledAlerts": [
                    ""
                ],
                "emailAddresses": [
                    ""
                ],
                "emailAccountAdmins": false,
                "retentionDays": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/vulnerabilityAssessments",
            "apiVersion": "2018-06-01-preview",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('servers_initialsql01_name'), '/Default')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('servers_initialsql01_name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "recurringScans": {
                    "isEnabled": false,
                    "emailSubscriptionAdmins": true
                }
            }
        },`

Comment: Could you add your ARM template to your question please ?

Comment: Hi Thomas, I just added the template parts regarding the SQL Server - hope it helps. Is it possible that many of those definition blocks are just 'optional', and the template export routine is just being to verbose.

Answer (score 0):

I have just removed all those SQL Server-related definitions I mentioned in the OP except for the primary creator definition* from the template JSON. Deployment was fine again, but no error messages anymore. Downside is that I apparently need to do this additional manual step after every template (re-)export :(

*I just kept:
`,
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
            "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
            "name": "[parameters('servers_initialsql01_name')]",
            "location": "[variables('rgLocation')]",
            "kind": "v12.0",
            "properties": {
                "administratorLogin": "[parameters('sqls01LI')]",
                "administratorLoginPassword": "[parameters('sqls01PW')]",
                "version": "12.0"
            }
        },`